# replacing integers with strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, getchar

I wrote code that replaces integers from `0` to `3` with `strings`. I was only allowed to use `getchar()` and `putchar()`. If the `input` is `1`, the output will become `"one"`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;            
    char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};
    int i;

        while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) 
        {
            if(c==0+'0') {
                char* str = arr[0];
                for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                    putchar(str[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(c==1+'0') {
                char* str = arr[1];
                for (i= 0; str[i] != '\0';i++) {
                    putchar(str[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(c==2+'0') {
                char* str = arr[2];
                for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                    putchar(str[i]);
                }
            }
            else if(c==3+'0') {
                char* str = arr[3];
                for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                    putchar(str[i]);
                }   
            }
            else
                putchar(c);
   }

return 0;
}
```

The `code` is pretty long. Is there a shorter way to write it?

If I type in `33` the output will be `"threethree"`. Could anyone give me suggestions how can i modify my code not to do that?

note: I am also not allowed to use functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to remember last input and compare, so that you will not print continuous char.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};
    int i;
    char last_input = '9';

    while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF)
    {
        if(c != last_input && '0' <= c  && c <= '3') {
            last_input = c;
            int index = c - '0';
            char* str = arr[index];
            for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                putchar(str[i]);
            }
        }
        else{
            putchar(c);
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but why is the last input '9'?

Comment: and it seems to work only once if input is 1 output will become "one" but if I type it a second time output will be 1

Comment: Isn't that what you want in your question?@makoto

Comment: The last input '9' can be any except 0 to 3. I just init it. You can also not init it.

Comment: oh sorry I should have been more specific if i type 11 then the output is oneone instead of 11.

Comment: >If I type in 33 the output will be "threethree". Could anyone give me suggestions how can i modify my code not to do that

Comment: Then why 3 is special?

Comment: it should only change the int to a string if it's only the single number 3 and not 33

Comment: @makoto Understand my code and change it. That's your task now.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress your if statements using one if condition like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;            
    char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};
    int i;

    while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) {
    int k = c-'0';
        if(k>=0 && k<=3) {
            char* str = arr[k];
            for (i= 0; str[i] != '\0';i++) {
                putchar(str[i]);
            }
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code will have `Segmentation fault` because '\n' will get by `getchar`, and '\n' - '0' is-38, which cause array overflow.

Comment: Thanks I dont quite understand why you subtract c-'0'

Comment: and if i write 11 it will print "oneone"

Comment: c-'0' will give the index from which we want to retrieve the string,

Comment: @makoto 11 should give oneone right ? Even your code gives output for 11 as oneone

Comment: @Uddhav know thats what I have been trying to change but I don't know how to change it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple approach to the same task. I tried to explain the logic in the comments.

```
int main(void) {
        char *arr[11] = {"zero", "one", "two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","Nine","Ten"};
        int *input = malloc(sizeof(*input))/*1st time 4 byte */ , row = 1;
        while( (input[row-1] = getchar())!=EOF ) {

                if(input[row-1]==10) /* if ENTER key is presed */
                        break;
                input[row-1] = input[row-1] - 48;/* convert it */
                printf("%s ",arr[ input[row-1]%10 ]);/* its simple, just think on it */
                row++;
                input = realloc(input,row * sizeof(*input));/* reallocate based on number of input */
        }
        /* free dynamically allocated memory @TODO*/
        return 0;
}
```

I just given hint, make it generic like write the condition if input is less than zero etc. I hope it helps.

Comment: Give the input like `5417` and check

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I am not allowed to ise printf or scanf only getchar and putchar

Comment: Sorry then I can't help. Anyway `Putchar()` means you are not storing anywhere, just printing on `stdout` and then gone. what's the use ?

Comment: Anyway in place of `print()` in my code you can replace with `putchar()` accordingly. `malloc()` is allowed to use or not ?

Comment: no malloc is also not allowed but thank you very much for taking your time to help me

Answer (score -1):

Here my code using loop to shorten your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c;            
    char* arr[4] = {"zero", "one", "two","three"};
    int i, j;

    while ((c = getchar ()) != EOF) 
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if(c == j + '0')
            {
                char* str = arr[j];
                for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
                {
                    putchar(str[i]);
                }
                j = 10; // just to detect processed character
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j != 10)
        {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```